# Form input values not held in session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this codeigniter project am working on. Am displaying some set of questions and I want to use pagination to display the questions in batches. Everything is working fine when first loaded (I mean on the first page) but when I navigate say to the next page, it fail to work. So I realize that the form input values are not held on the subsequent pages, so I decided to use session to hold these form values but it not still been held. My Controller:

```
public function displayQuestions()
{
    $sessData = [
        'classLevel' => $this->input->post('class_level'),
        'subject'   => $this->input->post('subject')
    ];

    $this->session->set_userdata($sessData);

    $config = array();

    $page = (($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0);

    $config["base_url"]     = base_url().'questions/displayQuestions';
    $config["total_rows"]   = 20;
    $config["per_page"]     = 5;
    $config["uri_segment"]  = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    // print_r($this->session->classLevel); exit;

    $data['questions'] = $this->questions_model->selectQuestions($this->session->classLevel, $this->session->subject, $config["per_page"], $page);

    // $this->load->view('layouts/header');
    $this->load->view('users/questions', $data);
    // $this->load->view('layouts/sidebar');
    // $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
}
```

Note: Am using the form input values to query the database to display the questions. My Model:

```
public function selectQuestions($classLevel, $subject, $limit, $start)
{
    $questions = $this->db->where('class_level', $classLevel)
                    ->where('subj_code', $subject)
                    // ->order_by('id', 'RANDOM')
                    ->limit($limit, $start)
                    ->get('questions');
    // $questions = $this->db->limit($limit, $start)
    //              ->get('questions');

    if ($questions->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $questions->result_array();
        // print_r($questions->result_array());
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I guess you reset the session data each time you call the displayQuestions method. And if the post data is empty the session gets zeroed again?

Comment: No am not resetting the session data. The session still hold some previous data passed to it.

Comment: But `'classLevel' => $this->input->post('class_level'),` sets session data for key `classLevel` to be post data, but if post data is empty you will reset the session?

Comment: I don't understand the part reset session

Comment: You use the command `$this->session->set_userdata($sessData);` - if `$sessData` is empty (due to no post data) then session will be emptied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess you are clearing all or parts of your session data when you navigate to the next page (which doesn't contain any POST data). Try to change the part

```
$sessData = [
    'classLevel' => $this->input->post('class_level'),
    'subject'   => $this->input->post('subject')
];
$this->session->set_userdata($sessData);
```

To:

```
if ($this->input->post('class_level') && $this->input->post('subject')):
    $sessData = [
        'classLevel' => $this->input->post('class_level'),
        'subject'   => $this->input->post('subject')
    ];
    $this->session->set_userdata($sessData);
endif;
```

meaning that you only set the session if data is previously posted.